# Adding a different colored line to each row of a table

Tags: formatting, color, longtable

It is possible to get colored `\hline`s with the example provided below. However, there are several issues with this implementation:

1. It needs a `\newcommand` for every color, which then has to be used as a replacement for the `\\` normally found at the end of each table row.
2. The color set globally with `\arrayrulecolor` is required to be copied into each `\newcommand` to reset the color back.

What other options are available to locally set the `\hline` color of a `longtable` or `tabular`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}             %need xcolor because otherwise color definitions won't work
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}

%tables: change color of table lines
\arrayrulecolor{gray!50}
%update the newline command to have a line at each row
\newcommand\tgln{\tabularnewline\hline}
%update the newline command to have a blue line at each row
\newcommand\tbln{\tabularnewline\arrayrulecolor{blue!30}\hline\arrayrulecolor{gray!50}}

\newcommand{\bs}{\begin{sideways}}
\newcommand{\es}{\end{sideways}}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.2cm}cp{2cm}c|p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}|}
    \caption{Overview of a table with a lot of numbers.}\label{tbl:numbers} \\
    \hline
    Name &  &Location   &Number 1   & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Items} \\
                        &   &                   &               &\bs Item 1 \es &\bs Item 2 \es &\bs Item 3 \es &\bs Item 4 \es &\bs Item 5 \es &\bs Item 6 \es &\bs Item 7 \es \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline \endfoot
    \hline \endlastfoot
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tgln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tgln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tgln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tgln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tgln
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2.2cm}cp{2cm}c|p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}p{0.15cm}|}
    \caption{Overview of a table with a lot of numbers.}\label{tbl:numbers} \\
    \hline
    Name &  &Location   &Number 1   & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Items} \\
                        &   &                   &               &\bs Item 1 \es &\bs Item 2 \es &\bs Item 3 \es &\bs Item 4 \es &\bs Item 5 \es &\bs Item 6 \es &\bs Item 7 \es \\
    \hline \endhead
    \hline \endfoot
    \hline \endlastfoot
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tbln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tbln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tbln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tbln
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tbln
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package might help.

Comment: It isn't really clear what your question is. You could obviously re-arrange the syntax of your locally defined commands, but any definitions are going to have to set the parameter for each table, so the top level syntax is just a matter of personal choice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. The question is now reformatted so the intention of it is clear. The `tabu` package was unknown to me, so that is indeed one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

How about a command with a color parameter?

```
\newcommand\tln[1]{\tabularnewline\arrayrulecolor{#1}\hline}
```

Then in your table

```
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tln{green}
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tln{red}
Some name    &Sometext   &Sometext  &100    &   &x  &   &   &   &   &\tln{blue}
```